# Make a list's column searchable

Tags: 2010, list, search, column

I have a normal custom list, I want somehow to enable the end user to do search on one of the list's columns

I've found [this](http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/add-custom-search-properties-in-your-advanced-search-sharepoint-2010/), but im looking for something simpler than this

*Sharepoint server 2010*

Answer (score 1):

You had to:

- Create a Site Column
- Add the Site Column to the List
- Go to the Search Center from Central Admin
- Add the mapping between your Site Column and a Name

If you can't find the column in the list, you can try to launch a Full Crawl

P.S.: the link you posted adds also the type to the search web part!

Comment: Well, Do I have to create a search center! or its already exists in the CA? plus, how to add mapping? I tried looking inside the `Search Service Application: Metadata Property Mappings` but nothing helped

Comment: Search Service Application -> Metadata Property Mappings is the right section.. There you must add a new Column.. You select the name and then the column to look.. Search your column's name betweek the choices, select it and push ok.

To check if it works, write down on a search box FieldName:Value : if doesn't tell you "cannot find column FieldName" means that the column has been mapped! Launch a full crawl and eveything will go fine